# Bootstrap accordion with a foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, typo3

my initial problem was that my accordions all opened at the same time but I understood that it was coming from the Id which was the same all the time.

So I tried to make my ID dynamic but that didn't solve my problem.
would you have a solution please? thank you

here is my code:

```html
<div class="accordion mb-5" id="accordion-infos">
  <f:for each="{field.container}" as="container"> 
    <!-- foreach bouton contenu -->
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="heading1-{container.buttoncontent}">
        <h2>
          <button class="accordion-button btn btn-link btn-block text-left" 
                  type="button" 
                  data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
                  data-bs-target="#collapseOne-{container.buttoncontent}" 
                  aria-expanded="true" 
                  aria-controls="collapseOne-{container.buttoncontent}">
            {container.buttoncontent}
          </button>
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne-{container.buttoncontent}" 
           class="accordion-collapse collapse" 
           aria-labelledby="heading1-{container.buttoncontent}" 
           data-bs-parent="#accordion-infos">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="section-card">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                <f:format.raw>{container.content}</f:format.raw>
              </div><!-- col-lg-6 col-md-6-->
            </div><!-- row-->
          </div><!-- section card -->
        </div> <!-- card body -->
      </div> <!-- collapsOne -->
    </div> <!-- card  -->
  </f:for><!-- endfor bouton contenu-->
</div><!-- accordion mb-5 -->
```

Comment: _"So I tried to make my ID dynamic but that didn't solve my problem."_ - why / how not? We don't know what data you are actually feeding into the shown template, so how are we supposed to know what result this actually produced now?

Comment: "So I tried to make my ID dynamic but that didn't solve my problem." i meant my accordion was no longer opening when i add dynamic content in my id,  I wanted to add to my id the name of my accordion button

Comment: So what does the generated HTML source look like? All IDs in there set as you thought they should be?

Comment: _"I wanted to add to my id the name of my accordion button"_ - and what do those names look like? Are they actually values, that when prefixed with `something-`, still result in a _valid_ value for an ID in HTML?

Comment: When I inspect the HTML with dynamics ID, I get that " <div id="collapseOne-vie pratique" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="heading1-vie pratique" data-bs-parent="#accordion-infos">  " So I get correctly my values but my accordion doesn't work

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id: _"id's value must not contain whitespace (spaces, tabs etc.)."_

Comment: that's the problem, I just tried to manually modify the id's with numbers on the inspector and it works.

Do you have any idea so that I can dynamically add numbers in my ID?

Comment: You could just replace the spaces in the value with an empty string. (But don't ask me how to do that within the templating language you are using there.)

Comment: I couldn't use this solution because the value is entered by a ckeditor, and values ​​will be entered by clients

Comment: I fixed it , my templating language is fluid and I can add an attribute "iteration" to make a loop :  <f:for each="{field.container}" as="container" iteration="itemIterator"> and I use it like that <div id="collapseOne-{itemIterator.cycle}" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="heading1-{itemIterator.cycle}" data-bs-parent="#accordion-infos">

Comment: But that should probably still fail, if you have multiple accordions on the same page ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using any editable text as an ID with restrictions is a bad idea in general.
for accordions or similar construction you always should use the `uid` from TYPO3. Or at least the `iterator.index` of a loop.

As you could have multiple accordions in one page you should combine it.

so your ID should consist of the `uid` of the container and the `uid`s of the contained elements.
Something like: `id="container-{data.uid}-{element.uid}"`
or

```html
<f:for each="{field.container}" as="container" iteration="iterator">
  :
     <div class="card-header" id="container-{data.uid}-{iterator.index}"`>
      :
      <div id="collapseOne-{data.uid}-{iterator.index}" ...
        :
```